# MDExpansion Panel - kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'panel_container'

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

I am currently building a mobile app with kivy. In one of my screens I am trying to include an MDExpansionPanel, although I have tried with a lot of different codes, and searched on the web for solutions, either I get an error, or simply the Expansion Panel is not rendered in my screen. I am using  ScreenManager since I have 5 screens, with the possibility of increasing such number.

The relevant Python code is the following:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker, MDTimePicker
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel 
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass

class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class TravelManagerWindow(Screen):
    pass


class IngActivWindow(Screen):
    panel_container = ObjectProperty(None)


    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.add_panels()

    def show_timepicker(self):
        picker = MDTimePicker()
        picker.bind(time=self.got_time)
        picker.open()

    def got_time(self, picker_widget, time):
        self.text = str(time.hour) + ":" + str(time.minute)
        self.focus = False
        # selectedTime= self.text
        print(self.text)
        self.ids.tiempoActiv.text = self.text

    def add_panels(self):
        for i in range(5):
            IngActivWindow.ids.panel_container.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon="actividades.png",
                    content=MyContent(),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(
                        text="Text",
                    )
                )
            )

class MyContent(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    ScreenManager().add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login'))
    ScreenManager().add_widget(CreateAccountWindow(name='create'))
    ScreenManager().add_widget(MainWindow(name='main'))
    ScreenManager().add_widget(IngActivWindow(name='ingActiv'))
    ScreenManager().add_widget(TravelManagerWindow(name='travelManager'))


class powerApp1(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    powerApp1().run()
```

The relevant kv code is the following:
(I have an image on the background and an Action Bar before the MDBoxLayout where I am trying to add the Expansion Panel)

```
<WindowManager>:
    LoginWindow:
    CreateAccountWindow:
    MainWindow:
    IngActivWindow:
    TravelManagerWindow:


<IngActivWindow>:
name: 'ingActiv'
panel_container: panel_container

FloatLayout:
    cols:1

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'ingActiv_background.png'

    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: '---------'
                with_previous: False

            ActionButton:

                icon: 'homeIcon.png'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.current = 'main'
                    root.manager.transition.direction =  'right'

            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Gastos de Viaje'
                mode: 'spinner'
                size_hint:(None,None)
                size: root.width/5,root.height/12

                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Solicitar'
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'solicitud'
                        root.manager.transition.direction =  'left'

                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Comprobar'
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'comprobar'
                        root.manager.transition.direction =  'left'

            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Opciones'
                mode: 'spinner'
                size_hint:(None,None)
                size: root.width/5,root.height/12

                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Ingresar Actividad'
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'ingActiv'
                        root.manager.transition.direction =  'left'

                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Enviar Reporte'

                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Cerrar Sesion'
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'login'
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'

    MDBoxLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint: 1,0.6
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: panel_container
                cols: 1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

<MyContent>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your support,
Have a great day.

Comment: `return WindowManager()` ???

Comment: My WindowManager(ScreenManager) class is where all the screen widgets are created. I'm actually new to Kivy and Python did I make a mistake by returning such class? My app runs okay though.

Comment: I'll edit my post so you can see it on the code.

Comment: Show a minimal example that users can run and look on your problem. You are giving a code that cannot be run and tested.

Comment: I edited my post so you can see all the relevant code. Sorry about that.

Comment: `LoginWindow`, `ScreenManager`, `CreateAccountWindow`, `MainWindow`, `IngActivWindow`, `TravelManagerWindow` - where is all this? Which screen is the problem? Show a **minimal example** that users can run and look on your problem

Comment: The screen in which I am trying to add the MDExpansion Panel is the IngActivWindow, which is why I only added the code of such screen. All the other screens have their own code but I am not adding such code for simplicity and because such code is not relevant for my problem.